# Is there a simple "Hello World" for making games?

Tags: application-development, games

Does anyone know of a simple "Hello World" for making games for ubuntu? I've seen the Getting Started with Quickly video.

Any examples for platformers or something like that?

EDIT:
Just a recap of the answers.

Blender Game engine -- Uses python

Pygame -- Python

MonoGame http://monogame.codeplex.com/ -- some sort of XNA ?

QuakeC -- This a Quake flavored C like lang.  See: Steel Storm http://one.steel-storm.com/

Comment: See: http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/

"Participate on AskUbuntu ›

A collaboratively-edited question and answer site for Ubuntu users and developers. 100% free, no registration required

Ask a question now ›" 

I think askubuntu is supposed to be for developers as well.

Comment: I personally feel this is fine, since on developer.u.c it's mentioned on AU. If the OP can get a little more specific on what they are looking for, then that'd be best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blender can make a 3D Game with Python: http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/features/

Is posible to make a simple hello world game there, its fully integrated with Sound, Physics simulation, GLSL, plugins for a lot of things (Networking and Web plugin included), good and professional workflow.

3D Platformer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGqyvX4P6Pg

Features Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjFGDcGcEjE

Panda3D its cool, but its not a Game Engine, its a bunch of Python Library where you can assemble a Game Engine, but its not fully and seamless integrated.

Ogre3D its like the same, its not a Game Engine, its just a 3D Graphics engine, where you can assemble a Game Engine, you have to code your own Sound for example.

Comment: I think Ogre3D and Panda3D are supposed to be a 3d graphics engines only and should be used with SFML or SDL to expand from 2d to 3d and with Bullet or PhysX to integrate physics. It's simple to do when you're already familiar with any of the above.

Answer (score 10):

One fast and easy option is [Quickly](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/quickly).

Creating a project is as easy as typing this at terminal:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application my-new-project
```

See this [intro video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssnlPS2dOqc&feature=player_embedded).

Also this is a great site: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

And, of course, the manual:  `man quickly`

You will be using python which is also great for 3d games, see [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/).

Comment: Yeah I would start with that one.

Comment: @desgua I've seen that video. Do you have any experience using Quickly as a starting point for game dev?

Comment: Im thinking Quickly + pygame(?) works well for like, point and click type games, maybe not so much to make platformers...

Comment: I can not agree with you. There are people even trying to use python code for Android games (just to make an example of the power of python) See this: http://kivy.org/#home

Comment: Pygame is pretty good http://www.pygame.org/news.html and if its just making great quick games Flash still can't be beat.

Answer (score 6):

Just like on any operating system you will need to choose a programming language that can use OpenGL for graphics. Then just develop the game.

Since a lot of applications on Ubuntu are open source you can find one in the software center that is free and use the following command:
    sudo apt-get source gameName
That will give you an idea of how games that already exist are made for Ubuntu. You can also research how to package debian packages for when you think you are ready for distribution.

Comment: Why the OpenGL requirement? There are many alternative libraries/languages that  can make games.

Comment: @Pubby can you name some?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out PyGame? it is a great library for making games. There is lots of games already made that you can read the code and learn a thing or two. I am currenlty devoting my free time in learning to make a platform game just for the sake of learning. I will post my learnings and reply later with some actual work

Please do check out http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials

Hope this helps

Comment: I have seen + used pygame some. Do you know of any real games that have been written in it? Real = A whole game (not just demos) with some decent graphics and game play

Answer (score 3):

Panda3D is a nice cross platform game library for Python and C++. It's developed and maintained by a group at Carnegie Mellon, and it has been used in a few commercial titles. It adds simpler abstractions over OpenGL, OpenAL, and Bullet, and there are a number of getting started examples available, including a 2D asteroids game.

http://www.panda3d.org/

http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Sample_Programs_in_the_Distribution

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advice to get interested in this: http://monogame.codeplex.com/

Comment: That looks pretty nice too.

Answer (score 1):

Some game engines that work with ubuntu are Panda3D and love2d. Both are very easy to learn and have good documentation and community.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple Hello World for games. The smallest Hello World ive ever been able to come up with for a game using just code, not quickly or pygame, is about 50 lines of C code that inits opengl and various C headers, sets up some opengl stuff and opens a window with hello world printed.

Game programming, even on Linux, is not as simple as most people think.

If you want something easier though, Blender 2.6 has a built in game engine, it uses Python and is very intuitive, but less flexible than straight C + OpenGL in my opinion.

Some resources:
nehe.gamedev.net
Google ;)
there are other floating around, i just cant remember the names of them, sorry :|.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to recommend qt and qml

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 50 line Tic-Tac-Toe:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton [] button  = new JButton [9];
    private int count = 0;

    public TicTacToe () {           
        super ("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        setSize (300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout (new GridLayout (3, 3));
        init ();
    }

    private void init () {           
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            button [i] = new JButton ("");
            button [i].addActionListener (this);
            add (button [i]);
        }
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a) {    
        String letter = (++count % 2 == 1) ? "X" : "O";
        for (JButton jb : button) 
        if (a.getSource () == jb) {
            jb.setText (letter);
            jb.setEnabled (false);
        }
        if (count == 9) {
            for (JButton jb : button) 
                remove (jb) ;
            init ();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {           
        new TicTacToe ();
    }
}
```

Since it is Java, it isn't bound to Ubuntu, not even Linux,  but will run on Solaris, Apple and Windows as well - where a JVM is.

But that is similar for solutions in Smalltalk, Python, Ruby, ... - even in C or C++ when a portable framework is used like Qt or Gnome, and not some proprietary MFC-classes. In C and C++, of course you have to recompile the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The simplicity of making games is based on the programming language/environment you choose. For advanced programmers, coding your game directly in a programming language of choice (C/C++/Python/Java/etc) may be the best way.

For hobbyists/non-coders who like a simple drag and drop interface to create games, I recommend 'Stencyl' (http://www.stencyl.com/).

The 'Stencyl' help website has all the resources for getting you started with creating games. You can also directly go to the 'Crash Course 2' help page to create your first game entirely from scratch in 'Stencyl' (http://www.stencyl.com/help/view/crash-course-invaders-1/). The 'Crash Course' is given in 'parts' and is very easy to follow.

Answer (score -1):

```
//A Hello World for game
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int a=5, answer;
    printf("I am guess number game\n\n"); getchar(); 
    printf("I have a number\n\n"); getchar();
    printf("...between 1 until 10...\n\n"); getchar();
    printf("Try to guess: \n\n"); scanf("%d", &answer);
    while(1){
    if(answer<a){printf("\nYours %d, too small...\n\nInput again: ", answer); scanf("%d", &answer);}
    if(answer>a){printf("\nYours %d, too big...\n\nInput again: ", answer); scanf("%d", &answer);}
    if(answer==a){printf("\nYou're Right! My number is %d!\n\nDa daaag...", a); break;}
             }
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Not much [replayability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_value)... ;-)